# A way to make onDeterminingFileName and NativeMessaging work together

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to determine if a file is already in my system before I download it.
I get the file name from the server through

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function (item, suggest) {

    var message = { "fileName": item.filename, "directory": directory };

    suggest({
        filename: item.filename,
        conflict_action: 'prompt',
        conflictAction: 'prompt'
    });

    // conflict_action was renamed to conflictAction in
    // https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/f1d784d6938b8fe8e0d257e41b26341992c2552c
    // which was first picked up in branch 1580.
});
```

which works great.

I am checking the filename through native messaging.

```
chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage("testcsharp", message, function (response) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            alert("ERROR: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        } else {
            isDownloaded = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)).data;

        }
    });
```

The problem is they are both asynchronous but I need to avoid the save as dialog if my file already exists and the only way I've found to do this is call chrome.downloads.cancel(item.id) but there is no guarantee that a response will come in time from native messaging to cancel in ondeterminingfilename. Is there a way to do this or am I just stuck notifying that this file already exists and closing the save dialog manually?

Comment: You could try: Always cancel. Then, restart the download when the information is available, if you actually want to download.

Comment: kind of clunky but it does work if I cancel grab the value from the asynchronous nativemessaging callback then redownload and keep track if download has been attempted.